# How to generate code coverage report in my xcode project?

Tags: xcode

i need full code coverage. Does anyone have any ideas for this. because I only get coverage for appdelegate and some other framework file.

Comment: Post only specific version of swift when making tags

Comment: @NitinSingh sure and thank you